# unable to install gnome and wine broken package in ubuntu 12.4

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, wine

I have Dell Vostro 3443 laptop. It has a certified pre-install [Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64-bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201402-14676/) by manufacturer. I have quite lot of software on it, updated using update manager. Now when I try to install wine and gnome it says broken packages, below is shows the logs generated by command line install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome
[sudo] password for mithun: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome : Depends: gnome-core (= 1:3.0+6ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: alacarte (>= 0.13.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: cheese (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: evolution (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
         Depends: evolution-plugins (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
         Depends: hamster-applet (>= 2.91.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: tomboy (>= 1.6) but it is not going to be installed or
                  gnote but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: vinagre (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gimp (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: inkscape (>= 0.48) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: simple-scan but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: epiphany-extensions (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gedit-plugins (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gnome-applets (>= 2.91) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: browser-plugin-gnash but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: gdebi but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: gnome-games-extra-data (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: liferea but it is not installable or
                     evolution-rss but it is not going to be installed or
                     blam but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: menu-xdg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and for the case of wine it will give as

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-client : Depends: adduser (>= 3.10) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: passwd
 ssh : Depends: openssh-server
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

and tried to install dependencies on my own. And followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) source.

Plus the command:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall
```

give the following list:

```
colord                      deinstall
cups                        deinstall
dell-eula                   deinstall
dell-recovery-bootloader            deinstall
deluge                      deinstall
deluge-gtk                  deinstall
dmraid                      deinstall
firstboot-video2                deinstall
hplip                       deinstall
indicator-printers              deinstall
kpartx-boot                 deinstall
libblas3gf                  deinstall
libboost-filesystem1.46.1           deinstall
libboost-python1.46.1               deinstall
libboost-system1.46.1               deinstall
libboost-thread1.46.1               deinstall
libdebconfclient0               deinstall
libdebian-installer4                deinstall
libdmraid1.0.0.rc16             deinstall
libevent-core-2.0-5             deinstall
libevent-openssl-2.0-5              deinstall
libgfortran3                    deinstall
libgl1-mesa-glx                 deinstall
libglapi-mesa                   deinstall
liblapack3gf                    deinstall
libmikmod2                  deinstall
libopts25                   deinstall
libportmidi0                    deinstall
libsane                     deinstall
libsdl-mixer1.2                 deinstall
libsdl-ttf2.0-0                 deinstall
libsmpeg0                   deinstall
libtorrent-rasterbar6               deinstall
libxatracker1                   deinstall
oem-config                  deinstall
oem-config-gtk                  deinstall
oobe-dim-disable                deinstall
printer-driver-gutenprint           deinstall
quilt                       deinstall
sane-utils                  deinstall
shotwell                    deinstall
user-setup                  deinstall
xserver-xorg                    deinstall
xserver-xorg-core               deinstall
xserver-xorg-video-intel            deinstall
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome           deinstall
xserver-xorg-video-vmware           deinstall
```

I removed them using:

```
$ dpkg --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1`
```

and tried to do update again still no use. The problem remains, am I missing any thing.

Edit : 2

Later it end up in complete os crash - not able to get log page also

The following are clear by now:

1. The manufacturer has given the ubuntu version as such - i.e., no modification. But with few additional packages.
2. The factory reset option is available(which I used later), but only available after system test for hardware done. Still don't know the reason for such behavior.
3. Even after factory reset cannot able to install wine.

Comment: Have you enabled all repositories?

Comment: yes. I dint mention above.

Comment: General (kind of) advice I can give is, GUI's are easier and (perhaps) better

Comment: @arsaKasra, I tried wine installing form Ubuntu Software Center. Its gives error with dependencies not fulfilled.

Comment: Now I am using Ubuntu 14.10, and wine is working fine (installed nvidia graphic drivers and updated once). But I don't know how wine can be installed in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

and now try the following:

> `sudo apt-get install -f packagename`

*#Please change the package name accordingly.*

I hope this will help as `-f` option fix the broken packages for you.  Good luck!